# Неразрешенный внешний символ | SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

При компиляции кода, выдает следующую ошибку:

`LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::Green" (?Green@Color@sf@@2V12@B)` и
`LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B)`

Подключенные библиотеки компоновщика:

```
winmm.lib
gdi32.lib
ws2_32.lib
opengl32.lib
libfreetype.a
libopenal32.a
libogg.a
libvorbis.a
libvorbisfile.a
libvorbisenc.a
libsfml-system-s.a
libsfml-window-s.a
libsfml-graphics-s.a
libflac.a
```

P.S. да, я знаю, много таких вопросов, но ни один вариант решения не подходит, и да, разрядность компьютера - х64, разрядность компилируемого проекта - x64, разрядность SFML -  x64

Comment: Сомнительно, что это весь текст ошибки. Ошибка с кодом LNK2001 говорит об использовании линкера MS. В то время как в списке подключенных библиотек фигурируют файлы `.a`, с которыми он не работает в принципе.

Comment: а может это от mingw файлы?

Comment: @KoVadim если я понимаю смысл вашего комментария, то первые 4 файла по идее должны быть встроены в mingw, а остальные получены из архива SFML (версии 2.5.1)

Comment: @user7860670 текст ошибки весь. Возможно, как раз из за этого; видимо линкер не принял файлы библиотек, но вроде как на сайте скачивания SFML x64 версии 2.5.1 нету другой версии

Comment: Вам следует собрать эту библиотеку самостоятельно тем тулкитом, который используется для сборки проекта. При использовании VS еще может прокатить ленивый вариант скачать SFML посредством vcpcg.

Comment: @TheNick-Ник мой комментарий о том, что версии скомпилированных библиотек должны совпадать с используемым компилятором (иногда с точностью до версии, но обычно должна совпадать версия ABI). файлы .а - это обычно gcc/mingw, .lib - это студийный компилятор. Какой именно компилятор Вы используете?

Comment: @KoVadim GCC 7.3.0

Comment: Ага, скорее всего это mingw. На сайте smfl есть как минимум две версии - GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (DW2) - 32-bit и GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit , они подходят по версии компилятора, но нужно ещё что бы совпала версия и битность компилятора.

Comment: @KoVadim версия та же, что и надо. и битность, и версия соблюдена. я еще попробовал через NuGet и через специальное расширение, но ничего не помогло

Comment: Специально погуглил. Вот прям Ваша проблема описана http://blog.kislenko.net/show.php?id=2806 причина - выбраны статические библиотеки для линковки.

Comment: Но если нужно все таки Статик, то открываем официальную доку https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php и ищем упоминание SFML_STATIC